# how to get count of multiple tables from oracle database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, count

I need to find out the count of large number of tables (eg: 40,50 tables) in below format where I will provide the table set (as parameters or list of tables).

In other words, I need to find the count of tables as below for a user defined table set.

```
TABLE_NAME :  ROW_COUNT
table_a    :   1000000
table_b    :   200000
table_c    :   450000
table_d    :   80000
```

etc..

1.) Is there a inbuilt option in sql developer or toad or any other tool to get count of multiple tables straight away?

2.) Is there a a sql statement or a pl/sql script that I can get above output?

**Note: Please note that I don't want to get the count of all the tables in schema. I want only specific list of tables. Ex: lets say there is 100 tables in the schema but I want only the count of 25 tables which i mention**

Answer (score 2):

A `PL/SQL` Block like this will work. Uses [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm) to dynamically execute a query string formed from table names fetched from [`ALL_TABLES`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2105.htm#REFRN20286),

```
DECLARE
    V_YOUR_SCHEMA VARCHAR2(30) ;
    V_COUNT NUMBER;
BEGIN
    V_YOUR_SCHEMA :='SCHEMA_NAME';

    FOR L_TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = v_YOUR_SCHEMA)
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || v_YOUR_SCHEMA ||'.' ||L_TABLE_NAME INTO V_COUNT;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_TABLE_NAME||' : '||V_COUNT);
    END LOOP;
 END;
 /
```

Snippet for Defined list of table names:

```
DECLARE
    V_YOUR_SCHEMA VARCHAR2(30) ;
    V_COUNT NUMBER;
    V_TABLE_LIST DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2_TABLE;
    TYPE V_LIST_TYPE is VARRAY(50) of VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    V_YOUR_SCHEMA :='SCHEMA_NAME';

    V_TABLE_LIST V_LIST_TYPE := V_LIST_TYPE('TABLE1', 'TABLE2', 'TABLE3');

    FOR L_ITER IN 1..V_TABLE_LIST.COUNT
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || v_YOUR_SCHEMA ||'.' ||V_TABLE_LIST(L_ITER) INTO V_COUNT;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_TABLE_LIST(L_ITER)||' : '||V_COUNT);
    END LOOP;
 END;
 /
```

> Note: View `ALL_TABLES` also has a column `num_rows`, which is populated
>   only if you collect statistics on the table with the `DBMS_STATS` package.

Comment: Why not select from USER_TABLES? Also `analyze` has been deprecated for more than a decade: always [use `DBMS_STATS` package](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm).

Comment: where to specify the table list?

Comment: In the `where` clause.

Comment: @rocxyjay added another sample